# Find the vector form of the equation for the line of intersection of the planes $x+y+z=8$ and $x+z=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So $n_1= \langle 1,1,1 \rangle$ and $n_2= \langle 1,0,1 \rangle$. If we cross multiply these we get $i-k$ or $\langle 1,0,-1 \rangle$. From here I set $y=0$ since the second plane has a $y$ value of $0$, and line up $x+z=8$ and $x+z=0$. From here I'm stuck and can't get an $x$ or $z$ value.

Comment: Why did you set $y = 0$? You found the normal vector which is great. All you need now is a point on the line. If you subtract $x+z=0$ from $x+y+z = 8$, you get $y = 8$. Great, now you can choose a point on the line by choosing an $x$ value, say $0$, and then you get $z = 0$. So $(0,8,0)$ is a point on the line. Do you know how to get the equation of a line given a point and direction?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: The two inconsistent equations that you’ve come up with tell you that there isn’t any point in the intersection with $y=0$.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way: solve the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y+z &=8\\
x+ z &=0\\
z&=t
\end{cases}
$$This gives $(x,y,z)=(-t,8,t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any two distinct points of the line; just take a pair of solutions of the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}x+y+z=8\\x+z=0,\end{array}\right.$$such as $(0,8,0)$ and $(1,8,-1)$. Then $(1,8,-1)-(0,8,0)=(1,0,-1)$ and so your line is$$\{(0,8,0)+\lambda(1,0,-1)\mid\lambda\in\Bbb R\}.$$